# How to change model by JQuery using JsRender technology?

Tags: jquery, jsrender, jsviews

I use jsViews in my project and faced with the problem:
When I change the value of input using JQuery the DOM is not changing.

I use custom tag:`{^{edit NOTE  holderWidth='90'/}}`,
`pm.mACQUAINTANCE.Items[2].row.NOTE` in DOM is "1111"
on aspx page `{^{edit}}` is tag 
 `<input id="472_ACQUAINTANCE_NOTE" class="valid" name="NOTE472">`

after `$("#472_ACQUAINTANCE_NOTE").val("2222");`
`$("#472_ACQUAINTANCE_NOTE").val()` will "2222", `pm.mACQUAINTANCE.Items[2].row.NOTE` in DOM is still "1111"

:( Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the value in the input using jQuery, and you want that value to trigger an update to the model, you will need to write

```
$("#472_ACQUAINTANCE_NOTE").val("2222").change();
```

or

```
$("#472_ACQUAINTANCE_NOTE").val("2222");
$("#472_ACQUAINTANCE_NOTE").change();
```

to trigger a DOM element change event - which will then trigger the data binding.

(You can also use either `change()` or `blur()`)